# Python extract text data in dynamic text format

Tags: python, string, split

I have very large text files that has the format below:

```
items=item1|item2|item3|item4&ids=18|117|34|315&locations=5|26|9|12#Characteristic_1#Describe Characteristic_1#http://example.com
items=item1|item2|item3|item4&ids=18|117|34|315&locations=5|26|9|12#Characteristic_2#Describe Characteristic_2#http://example.com
items=item1|item2|item3|item4&ids=18|117|34|315&locations=5|26|9|12#Characteristic_3#Describe Characteristic_3#http://example.com
```

The number of items, ids and locations is not fixed, it has 4 value above, but it also has 1,2,3 or 5, 6 value like below example:

```
items=item1&ids=18&locations=5#Characteristic_1#Describe Characteristic_1#http://example.com
items=item1|item2&ids=18|117&locations=5|26#Characteristic_1#Describe Characteristic_1#http://example.com
items=item1|item2|item3&ids=18|117|34&locations=5|26|9#Characteristic_3#Describe Characteristic_1#http://example.com
```

What I want to get from this data is the item name and its id, also its location. Like below format:

```
item1,18,5
item2,117,26
item3,34,9
item4,315,12
```

I have tried to use split("|") function to get the value out of string, but i don't figure out:

1. How to deal with the dynamic number of items exists in the string and
2. How to match the value to each other accordingly.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> s = "items=item1|item2|item3&ids=18|117|34&locations=5|26|9#Characteristic_3#Describe Characteristic_1#http://example.com"
```

**To get values for one parameter:**

Split by '&' and get the first parameter.

```
>>> s.split('&')[0]
'items=item1|item2|item3'
```

Split that by '=' and get the value and remove the key (i.e. "items")

```
>>> s.split('&')[0].split('=')[1]
'item1|item2|item3'
```

Split the value by '|'

```
>>> s.split('&')[0].split('=')[1].split('|')
['item1', 'item2', 'item3']
```

**Similarly you can get values for the other parameters:**

```
>>> s.split('&')[1].split('=')[1].split('|') # Notice the [1] in the first split
['18', '117', '34']
```

**And then you just have to combine these multiple lists in whatever way you like.**

Comment: About the 2nd problem, since the size of arrays is the same, so i just need to get the length of one array and print out values of each element inside each arrays.

Comment: Yeah, that would work. So the assumption here is that the request will give you equal number of values for each key.

Comment: Yes, the data is pretty structured so it is easier to process

Comment: Sorry varunl, i don't have enough reputation right now (11) to accept your answer. Sure that i will do it when I get enough reputation.

Comment: Sorrry varunl, i thought that i need to vote up to get the answer accepted. I have already do that. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

This should work,

```
item=item.split('#')[0]
item = item.split('&')
item[1]=item[1].lstrip('ids=')
item[2]=item[2].lstrip('locations=')
itemTemp = zip(item[0].split('|'),item[1].split('|'),item[2].split('|'))
print itemTemp
```